# What conjugation does出す/出せる take in this expression;元気を出せよ。?

Tags: meaning, expressions, conjugations

Now i know that 元気を出せよ。=Cheer up.
But i have no clue what's going on in the expression.

Here's my attempt to literally translate it with the help of Jisho.org:

元気を出せよ。=You can reveal/show full spirit/livelyhood, you know.
Supposing that 出す is in potential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **出す** is in it's imperative form(command form). according to [this site](https://www.japanistry.com/the-imperative/) the **よ** at the end of the sentence is helping to soften the use of the imperative.A bit more info can be found on the site; I recommend checking it out as it goes over the basics of imperative verbs quite extensively.

Here are two example sentences I pulled from Tangorin I hope this helps show imperative vs. potential.
[image]

I hope I was able to help even just a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer about the conjugation of the verb 出す, which was more than sufficient.
Do you have any comment about 元気を出せよ。=  Hey! Reveal/show full spirit/livelyhood. translation?

Comment: I think that works great. sorry if you wanted more lol I tried to think more critically  about it, but overall I personally think it is a good translation.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the potential form, it's the imperative / command form of 出す. The form for issuing commands. For a godan verb like 出す, you change the final mora to the equivalent え column character.

だす > だせ
きく > きけ
のむ > のめ
はしる > はしれ
さそう > さそえ

The final よ is the sentence-ending emphasis particle よ.

Jisho actually shows inflections of verbs. If you go to the entry for 出す and click "show inflections" you'll see the imperative form at the bottom.